# Is there a permutation $\tau\in S_n$ with $\tau(1)^{\tau(2)}+\cdots+\tau(n-1)^{\tau(n)}+\tau(n)^{\tau(1)}$ a square?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, diophantine-equations, additive-combinatorics, permutations

Let $n>1$ be an integer, and let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of all the permutatins of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
I'm curious whether there is a permutation $\tau\in S_n$ such that
$$\tau(1)^{\tau(2)}+\cdots+\tau(n-1)^{\tau(n)}+\tau(n)^{\tau(1)}$$
is a square. (Without loss of generality we may assume that $\tau(n)=n$.)  For $n=2,3$ there is no such a permutation $\tau$. But my computations for $n=4,5,\ldots,11$
lead me to formulate the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** For any integer $n>3$, there is a permutation $\tau\in S_n$ such that
$$\tau(1)^{\tau(2)}+\cdots+\tau(n-1)^{\tau(n)}+\tau(n)^{\tau(1)}$$
is a square.

For example,
$$2^1 + 1^3 + 3^4 + 4^2 = 10^2, \ \ 1^5 + 5^2 + 2^4 + 4^3 + 3^6 + 6^1 = 29^2,$$
and
$$1^3 + 3^2 + 2^{10} + 10^5 + 5^7 + 7^8 + 8^6 + 6^9 + 9^4 + 4^{11} + 11^1 = 4526^2.$$
For more examples and related data, one may consult http://oeis.org/A342965.

**QUESTION.** Is the above conjecture true?

You are welcome to check the conjecture further.

Comment: Why is this interesting? You have $(n-1)!$ shots in the range $[0,n^n]$ (or so). The chances of hitting a square grow fast towards $1$ as $n$ grows.

Comment: Maybe there is a secret hope to find a pattern which yields a solution for each n...

Comment: (But such a pattern would surely be VERY surprising)

Comment: Let $a(n)$ denote the number of permutations $\tau\in S_n$  with $\tau(n)=n$ satisfying the requirement in the conjecture. I have computed $a(n)$ for $n=4,\ldots,11$, namely, $$a(4)=1,\ a(5)=2,\ a(6)=1,\ a(7)=a(8)=6,\ a(9)=10,\ a(10)=27.$$

Comment: I have verified the conjecture for $n=12$ with the example $$1^2 + 2^5 + 5^6 + 6^8 + 8^4 + 4^{11} + 11^9 + 9^7 + 7^{10} + 10^3 + 3^{12}+ 12^1 = 51494^2$$. Jinyuan Wang has computed $a(n)$ for $n=11,12,13$ (cf. http://oeis.org/A342965), their values are $$a(11)=105,\ a(12)=245,\ a(13)=525.$$  In view of the values of $a(4),\ldots,a(13)$, it seems that $a(n)$  does not grow quickly. By Stirling's formula, $n!\sim (n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun Randomly one expects $a(n)$ to be at least as large as $(n-1)!/(n-1)^{n/2}$ (significantly higher as the worst case upper bound occurs only $1/(n-1)$ of cases).  This doesn’t look that large for small $n$ but it surely grows faster than exponentially.